# Could we use "I have a chat" instead of "I have got a chat"?

Tags: difference

- We can use have or have got to talk about possession, relationships,
  illnesses, **appointment** etc.
- We use have (but not have got) for things we do or experience.
  **For example:** have  a breakfast/ a dream/ **a chat/ a conversation (with somebody)**

This information is from  *English Grammar In Use Fifth Edition*.

Could we use "I *have* a chat/ a conversation" instead of "I *have got* a chat/ a conversation"?

I think both of them talk about appointment.

Please give me some examples.

Comment: The passage you quote _tells_ you that we cannot say 'I have got a chat.'! If you are unsure, don't use _got_ at all (unless you mean _obtained_ or _fetched_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"a chat" or "a conversation" are not things you can *possess*.  They are activities which you *do*.  Given this, as you can see from the definition you quoted, you can *not* use "have got" with "chat"/"conversation".  You must use "have".

I think you may be confused because an "appointment" is not the same thing as what the appointment is *for*.  An "appointment to visit the doctor" is not the same thing as "visiting the doctor".  Visiting the doctor is an action, but an appointment is not an action itself, it is just a reservation or agreement of a time/place to do that action in the future.  You can obtain or possess an appointment, but you cannot obtain or possess the activity of actually (later) going and doing whatever it is you have the appointment for.

So you can say "I've got an appointment to have a chat with Bob" (meaning that you have obtained an agreement to do it at some point in the future), but you would say "I had a chat with Bob" or "I have had a chat with Bob" (meaning that it's something you actually did).